# Freeze Panes in OpenXml SDK 2.0 for Excel document

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm generating an Excel workbook using OpenXml and have been following the examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837.aspx

It would be really useful if I could freeze the top panes, but I can't find a way to do this. I realise that I can do this if I use http://closedxml.codeplex.com/ but for now I'd like to stick to the OpenXml SDK

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was trying to solve the same problem and ended up opening the Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool and using the `Compare Files...` feature to compare two spreadsheets, one with frozen panes and one without.

When I did that, I was led to code that looked basically like this:

```
WorkbookPart wbp = doc.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.WorksheetParts.First();

SheetViews sheetviews = wsp.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();
SheetView sv = sheetviews.GetFirstChild<SheetView>();
Selection selection = sv.GetFirstChild<Selection>();
Pane pane = new Pane(){ VerticalSplit = 1D, TopLeftCell = "A2", ActivePane = PaneValues.BottomLeft, State = PaneStateValues.Frozen };
sv.InsertBefore(pane,selection);
selection.Pane = PaneValues.BottomLeft;
```

I added this to my program and it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: I was using the code above and was generating an exception. Turns out that I had not made an actual selection in the spreadsheet I was using, so the selection object was a null reference.  Selecting "A2" got me through.

Comment: how are you creating your worksheet? I am creating mine in memorystream and when I go to freeze a row, using the above code I get sheetviews null exception.

Answer (score 7):

You can add the Selection as well:

```
WorkbookPart wbp = doc.WorkbookPart;
WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.WorksheetParts.First(); 

SheetViews sheetViews = wsp.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetViews>();
SheetView sheetView = sheetViews.GetFirstChild<SheetView>();

Selection selection1 = new Selection() { Pane = PaneValues.BottomLeft };

Pane pane1 = new Pane() { VerticalSplit = 1D, TopLeftCell = "A2", ActivePane = PaneValues.BottomLeft, State = PaneStateValues.Frozen };

sheetView.Append(pane1);
sheetView.Append(selection1);
```

Comment: Order of operations matter. You need to add the SheetViews to the Worksheet before adding the SheetData.

Answer (score 6):

When I used the code provided in the other answers, I kept receiving a null error for the SheetViews.  I used the SDK Productivity Tools to view the code for an excel document with a frozen pane, which helped me create the below code.  Instead of using the GetFirstChild method, I had to create new instances of the SheetViews and SheetView classes and append them.

Here is the code.

```
WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

SheetViews sheetViews = new SheetViews();
SheetView sheetView = new SheetView() { TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U };
Pane pane = new Pane() { ActivePane = PaneValues.BottomLeft, State = PaneStateValues.Frozen, TopLeftCell = "A2", VerticalSplit = 1D };
Selection selection = new Selection() { Pane = PaneValues.BottomLeft };
sheetView.Append(pane);
sheetView.Append(selection);
sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(sheetViews);
```

One extra note is that when creating the SheetView, you must include the TabSelected and WorkbookViewId values, otherwise you will receive an error when opening the file about "We found a problem with some content in...."

Also, for anyone who wants to freeze the first column, instead of the first row, here is an example.

```
var sheetViews = new SheetViews();
var sheetView = new SheetView() { TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U };
var pane = new Pane() { ActivePane = PaneValues.TopRight, HorizontalSplit = 1D, State = PaneStateValues.Frozen, TopLeftCell = "B1" };
var selection = new Selection() { Pane = PaneValues.TopRight };
sheetView.Append(pane);
sheetView.Append(selection);
sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Feedback from 03/02/2021 :**

You just have to add in your generation class the content of the Excel file, this :

```
Pane FrozeShutterLine1= new Pane() { VerticalSplit = 1D, TopLeftCell = "A2", ActivePane = PaneValues.BottomLeft, State = PaneStateValues.Frozen };
```

This line allows indeed, to freeze all the shutters of the upper line...

Code of a spreadsheet without the fixed shutters :
[image]

Code of a spreadsheet with fixed shutters :
[image]

I share this feedback because I also searched for a while before finding out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MemoryStream documentStream = new ();
    SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(documentStream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    WorkbookStylesPart stylePart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
    stylePart.Stylesheet = new ScrapBuyplanStyleSheet().GenerateStyleSheet();
    stylePart.Stylesheet.Save();
    
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
    
    // Freeze Panes
    SheetViews sheetViews = new ();
    SheetView sheetView = new () {TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value) 0U};
    Pane pane = new ()
    {
        ActivePane = PaneValues.TopRight,
        State = PaneStateValues.Frozen, 
        TopLeftCell = "B1", 
        //VerticalSplit = 1D,
        HorizontalSplit = 1D
    };
    Selection selection = new () {Pane = PaneValues.TopRight};
    sheetView.Append(pane);
    sheetView.Append(selection);
    sheetViews.Append(sheetView);
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(sheetViews);
```

Solution to null pointer when creating pane is create the worksheet before adding the pane

Answer (score 0):

**Large Data OpenDocument Writer Example**

After Much Trial and Error, and using [this Example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/site/file?hash=0xb8be58af683213ece765e81ab0a14d7d9b657658de7978bd45a2135bd377deda) I found the SheetViews Goes inside the Worksheet at the top.  In My case to write large amounts of data I use a streaming and writer approach.  I place this here because it's where Google landed me for others.

**Freeze First Column Example**

```
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(uniqueFilePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                List<OpenXmlAttribute> attributeList;
                OpenXmlWriter writer;
                workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
                var workSheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(workSheetPart);
                /* <Worksheet> */
                writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());

                /*<SheetViews>*/
                writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetViews());

                var tabSelectedAtt    = new OpenXmlAttribute("tabSelected", null, 1.ToString());
                var workBookViewIdAtt = new OpenXmlAttribute("workbookViewId", null, 0.ToString());

                writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetView(), new List <OpenXmlAttribute>()
                {
                    tabSelectedAtt, workBookViewIdAtt
                });

                var xSplitAtt      = new OpenXmlAttribute("xSplit", null, 1.ToString());
                var topLeftCellAtt = new OpenXmlAttribute("topLeftCell", null, "B1");
                var activePane     = new OpenXmlAttribute("activePane", null, "topRight");
                var state          = new OpenXmlAttribute("state", null, "frozen");

                writer.WriteStartElement(new Pane(), new List <OpenXmlAttribute>()
                {
                    xSplitAtt, topLeftCellAtt, activePane, state
                });
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                /*</SheetViews>*/


                /* <Columns> */
                writer.WriteStartElement(new Columns());
                int columnsCounter = 1;
                var columnData = reader.GetColumnSchema();
                foreach (var c in columnData) {
                    /* <Column> */
                    attributeList = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                    attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("min", null, columnsCounter.ToString()));
                    attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("max", null, columnsCounter.ToString()));
                    attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("width", null, ((150 /*Width*/ / 6) + 2).ToString())); //attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("width", null, ((col.Width / 6) + 2).ToString()));                            
                    writer.WriteStartElement(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Column(), attributeList);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();                            
                    columnsCounter++;
                    /* </Column> */
                }
                writer.WriteEndElement();
                /* </Columns> */

                /* <SheetData> */
                writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());

                //...
```

**Freeze First Row Example**

using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(uniqueFilePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
List attributeList;
OpenXmlWriter writer;
workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
var workSheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart();
writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(workSheetPart);
/*  */
writer.WriteStartElement(new Worksheet());

```
/*<SheetViews>*/
writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetViews());

var tabSelectedAtt    = new OpenXmlAttribute("tabSelected", null, 1.ToString());
var workBookViewIdAtt = new OpenXmlAttribute("workbookViewId", null, 0.ToString());

writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetView(), new List <OpenXmlAttribute>()
{
    tabSelectedAtt, workBookViewIdAtt
});

var xSplitAtt      = new OpenXmlAttribute("ySplit", null, 1.ToString());
var topLeftCellAtt = new OpenXmlAttribute("topLeftCell", null, "A2");
var activePane     = new OpenXmlAttribute("activePane", null, "bottomLeft");
var state          = new OpenXmlAttribute("state", null, "frozen");



writer.WriteStartElement(new Pane(), new List <OpenXmlAttribute>()
{
    xSplitAtt, topLeftCellAtt, activePane, state
});
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndElement();

/*</SheetViews>*/


/* <Columns> */
writer.WriteStartElement(new Columns());
int columnsCounter = 1;
var columnData = reader.GetColumnSchema();
foreach (var c in columnData) {
    /* <Column> */
    attributeList = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
    attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("min", null, columnsCounter.ToString()));
    attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("max", null, columnsCounter.ToString()));
    attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("width", null, ((150 /*Width*/ / 6) + 2).ToString())); //attributeList.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("width", null, ((col.Width / 6) + 2).ToString()));                            
    writer.WriteStartElement(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Column(), attributeList);
    writer.WriteEndElement();                            
    columnsCounter++;
    /* </Column> */
}
writer.WriteEndElement();
/* </Columns> */

/* <SheetData> */
writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());
```